# Forcing cleanup in Microsoft Security Essentials

Tags: ms-security-essentials

I did a full scan recently. It went on and on and on. So I cancelled it. It said that some malware had been found. But when I cancelled the scan, it simply skipped cleaning up. Is there some way to force it to clean up malware as it gets found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just let MSE finish it's scan - most antivirus and anti-malware programs finish their scans first, and then clean up.

You might also want to look at [Malwarebyte's Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php) program. The free version is a great scanner and malware remover (you only need to pay if you want the additional features:  realtime protection, scheduled scanning, and scheduled updating).

If you have any problems running Malwarebyte's Anti-Malware, check out [this tutorial at Bleeping Computer](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/how-to-use-malwarebytes-anti-malware-tutorial) - it walks you through the basics of how to use it, as well as how to work around a virus that actively blocks Malwarebyte's (it's so much more fun when the virus tries to fight back!).

Comment: Weird. I think it's more common sense to atleast remove viruses that have already been detected.

Comment: They do it that way because some "tools" are detected as malware, or are a false positive and users may not want them removed, they want a choice. All on demand scanners that I know of scan first, then allow you to look over what it found and decide if you want all it found to be removed, this is preferred by most.